How to detect multiple tabs with same base domain?
If I have a web app deployed to multiple sub-domains with the base domain being same (abc.example.com, def.example.com ... xyz.example.com and so on), is it possible to detect when a user has multiple tabs opened with the different sub-domains in the same browser? e.g. if a user opens both abc.example.com and xyz.example.com in the same browser, it should detect that.
I looked into Broadcast Channel API but found that it doesn't work cross-origin so that doesn't seem to be an option.

Not unless those tabs hold references to one another.

"it should detect that" - for what exact purpose? What do you need this info for, what do you intend to do with it?
